# Mock objects outside my test method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

i write units tests to test some dll loading. In my test case i want that my static method Utils.loadLibrary returns always a valid object. Inside my test case that is no problem but when i call a new method inside my test case the mocking didnt work. Is it possible to mock whole methods while my unit test is running?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Utils.class)
public class ControlTest {
    private static final String ROOT = "Root\\";

    @Test
    public void testCapturing() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Utils.class);
        Mockito.when(Utils.loadLibrary(Matchers.anyString(),Matchers.any())).thenReturn(new Object()); 

        final Object o = Utils.loadLibrary("", null);

        final String[] paths = new String[2];

        final String scriptPathLeft = this.getClass().getResource("folder/Script_0.txt").getPath();
        final String scriptPathRight = this.getClass().getResource("folder/Script_1.txt").getPath();
        paths[0] = scriptPathLeft;
        paths[1] = scriptPathRight;

        final Params params = new Params(ROOT);
        final String PathLeft = ROOT + "\\Folder";
        final String PathRight = ROOT + "\\Folder";

        final File FileLeft = new File(PathLeft);
        final File FileRight = new File(PathRight);

        nikonFileLeft.mkdirs();
        nikonFileRight.mkdirs();

        final Control control = new Control(nikonImagePathLeft, nikonImagePathRight, params);

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            if (!paths[i].isEmpty()) {
                control .prepareScriptExecution(paths[i], nikonImagePathLeft, i == 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the method prepareScriptExecution I call Utils.LoadLibrary and want that this method returns my mock object and not null. I dont want to load dlls in my test case.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: And you're calling `Utils.loadLibrary` with an empty String and `null` in `#prepareScriptExecution`? Sounds strange.

Comment: No, i used that only for testing. In #prepareScriptExecution i call Utils.loadLibrary(LibraryName, Classobject). In my test i dont need a real object. Only an object.

Comment: Well you said `when(Utils.loadLibrary("", null))`, not `when(Utils.loadLibrary(anyString(), any()))` ... so it expects an empty String and `null`.

Comment: I changed the line `Mockito.when(Utils.loadLibrary("", null)).thenReturn(new Object());` to `Mockito.when(Utils.loadLibrary(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.any())).thenReturn(new Object());`

Comment: Another question: Is it possible to mock all methods from an interface without using a mock object? So that i define in an initMethod all behaviour and then later my method use this behaviour  as reference?